# User defined data types in T-sql

Tags: sqldatatypes

I had a look in the tables I am using in my database based on Rapid SQL. In one of the table i was just checking columns used in that table. I used sp_help table_name to find out the details of columns, datatypes and other things. I found some data types as T_gender_domain, T_name_domain, T_phone_domain. Are they used as a user defined data types???